# weblogic <BEA_000499> warning

Tags: java, weblogic

I am doing the file operations (file copying from one location to another) . 
When the file size is less than 2GB copying is working fine. But, if it is more than that , giving

```
<BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on ***.***.***.***:port_no, during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs>
```

Code goes as below,

```
private void copyFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    String uploadedFileLocation, boolean append) {
    File publicFile;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        publicFile=new File(uploadedFileLocation);
        out = new FileOutputStream(publicFile,append);
        int read;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in transfering file" +e.getMessage());
    }finally
    {
        try{
        if(out!=null)out.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Solution I got after browsing is  tuning of the server. Is there any other way I can make it work ?

Comment: Please show some code. How exactly you do copying?

Comment: It is web service limit. I don't know about any simple solution. Maybe using flash or java applet you can split big file, post it to server part by part and merge on server side. Maybe someone know better and can help you.